# fetch attributes value from getLoadedProductCollection and stored into array

Tags: magento, collections, catalog

I want to fetch the url of product.
Below I have displaying from getLoadedProductCollection method on Category Page.

Also, I have to stored product name, price, url, images of product into array.

```
<?php $products = $this->getLoadedProductCollection();?>

[url_path] => Array
(
    [SCHEMA_NAME] => 
    [TABLE_NAME] => catalog_product_flat_1
    [COLUMN_NAME] => url_path
    [COLUMN_POSITION] => 39
    [DATA_TYPE] => varchar
    [DEFAULT] => 
    [NULLABLE] => 1
    [LENGTH] => 255
    [SCALE] => 
    [PRECISION] => 
    [UNSIGNED] => 
    [PRIMARY] => 
    [PRIMARY_POSITION] => 
    [IDENTITY] => 
)
```

How Can i fetch the data and stored into array.

Answer (score 0):

use addUrlRewrite method

```
$products = $this->getLoadedProductCollection()->addUrlRewrite()->load();
```

**UPDATE** some example how you put this into an array

```
foreach($products as $product) {
    $productsArray[$product->getId()] = $product->getData();
    $productsArray[$product->getId()]['url'] = $product->getProductUrl();
}
```

Comment: I am getting same data as I have posted in question. Below is the structure what I am getting when I print $products->getLoadedProductCollection().

Comment: url_path is not what you need. you also cannot simply print return values of methods in model objects. When you iterate through $products use $product->getProductUrl() to get generic url from magento rewrite engine. If it is what you want

Comment: Yes I have implemented it. We can not print return values. But I want to fetch name, url, images, price, description into an array.
How Can We do that from getLoadedProductCollection.

Comment: see updated answer. you will get 2 dimensional array with product ids as key and product attributes incl. url as array in value